# Powershell indent here-string

Tags: powershell

Does anybody know if it is possible to intend a `here-string`. Actually I've to write:

```
  $someString = @"
                First line
                second line
  "@
```

This becomes very ugly if you define a `here-string` on a deeper indentation level, because the ending `"@` must be the first character on the line. Additionally somebody might "fix" the missing indentation and break the script ...

Is it possible to define a `here-string` like:

```
  $someString = @"
                First line
                second line
                "@
```

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closing `"@` must be at the start of the line.

I agree with you that this can make the script file harder to read, but it is the rule, and there is no way around it as far as I know.

You can find a uservoice entry [here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11087706-allow-whitespace-between-final-newline-and-quotati), and you should vote for it if you feel this is important to you. It does not look like a priority at the moment, with only 3 votes, but the more votes, the higher the priority for the powershell team to look into it.

Comment: [From about_Quoting_Rules:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) _"In either format, the closing quotation mark must be **the first character in the line.**"_

Answer (score 3):

Late answer (technically "workaround"), I know, but this is currently one of the first search results for "PowerShell here-string indentation".

> This becomes very ugly if you define a here-string on a deeper indentation level

I agree.  For those of us concerned with the aesthetics of the resulting code, I found the following workaround on [this TechNet question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be1dac5d-6cee-4f5d-86d3-9dc85cbd44be/here-string-formatting?forum=winserverpowershell).

It's definitely *not* a here-string (*especially* since you must still escape embedded quotes), but at least for many multi-line use-cases, it will serve the same purpose, and allow you to keep indenting at the same level as the rest of the code-block:

```
$somestring = (
    "First line",
    "Second line"
) -join "`r`n"
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon @NotTheDr01ds's answer, you can make it even more aesthetically pleasing by excluding commas after each item. So long as each item in the array is on its own line:

```
$HTML = @(
   "<h1>OIDC Services are <font style='color:green'>Online</font></h1>"
   "<br/><p>Your identity: <ul><li>Username: $($Context.User.Identity.Name)</li></ul></p>"
   "<br/><p>Troubleshooting: <ul><li><a href='/restart-service'>Restart Service</a></li></ul></p>"
) -Join "`n"
```